# Can a percentage be referred to as a "total"?

Tags: grammar, ielts

Can I use "**total**"and "****amount** to**" with % like the following sentence :

The largest category of digital communicators was the group aged 13 to 25 ,Which **totaled**/**amounted** **to** 40% of the total users.

Comment: **Amounted to** is better. **Made up** is simpler still. And how about **of all users**?

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on the context, but as a general rule, I would not recommend referring to a percentage as "an amount" as they are two very different things.

For example, if you had a cohort of 200 people, of which 100 were male and 100 were female, the *amount* of women is 100, but the *percentage* of women is 50.

I would say:

> The largest category of digital communicators was the group aged 13 to 25, which **represented** 40% of the total users.

The same is true of the word "total" and "totalled" - these refer to aggregated values. When percentages are represented along with subtotals, the grand total is usually referred to as the *overall percentage*, not the "total percentage".

A good way to think of a percentage is that it is basically a *fraction* where the denominator is always 100. If you can't say it about a fraction, you shouldn't say it about a percentage, and you wouldn't say "they amounted to a third", for example.